# How to scrape a website, http get vs http post?

Tags: java, http, scrape

I am new to programming and know very little about http, but I wrote a code to scrape a website in Java, and have been running into the issue that my code scrapes "get" http calls (based on typing in a URL) but I do not know how to go about scraping data for a "post" http call.

After a brief overview on http, I believe I will need to simulate the browser, but do not know how to do this in Java. [The website](http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/SheriffSearch/results.aspx?q=searchType=SaleDate&searchString=10/7/2013&foreclosureType=%27TAX%27,%20%27TAXB%27) I have been trying to use.

As I need to scrape that source code for all the pages, the URL does not change as each next button is clicked. I have used Firefox firebug to look at what is going on when the button is clicked, but I do not know all that I am looking for.

My code to scrape the data as of now is:

```
public class Scraper { 
  private static String month = "11";
  private static String day = "4";
  private static String url = "http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/SheriffSearch/results.aspx?q=searchType%3dSaleDate%26searchString%3d"+month+"%2f"+day+"%2f2013%26foreclosureType%3d%27NONT%27%2c+%27PAR%27%2c+%27COMM%27%2c+%27TXLN%27"; // the input website to be scraped

  public static String sourcetext; //The source code that has been scraped

  //scrapeWebsite runs the method to scrape the input URL and returns a string to be parsed.
  public static void scrapeWebsite() throws IOException {

    URL urlconnect = new URL(url); //creates the url from the variable
    URLConnection connection = urlconnect.openConnection(); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                                                                 connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")); 
    String inputLine; 
    StringBuilder sourcecode = new StringBuilder(); // creates a stringbuilder which contains the sourcecode

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
      sourcecode.append(inputLine);
    in.close();
    sourcetext = sourcecode.toString(); 
  }
```

What would be the best way to go about scraping all the pages for each "post" call?

Comment: You would need to scrape all `form` elements that have a `post` `method` attribute value. Keep track of all their `input` elements, serialize them and send the requests.

Comment: _"I am new to programming and know very little about http"_ -- you should take a week or two to read up on HTTP, HTML and modern website architecture.  Scraping websites generally works only with older sites that do not use Javascript to manipulate the DOM at presentation time.  To "scrape" a modern JS-based site you would have to emulate a full-featured browser in your code.  Most of the UI elements might not even exist in the HTTP stream; they would be created by the Javascript on the client browser after the initial download.

Comment: Jim, I am writing this based off a previous Ruby code that no longer works, which did emulate a full-featured browser. So this can be done in Java? If so is there a set of classes I could read up on to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [jersey client interface](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#client)

View the source of each page and determine the pattern of the url for next an previous pages then loop through.

Comment: For my website, the URL does not change when the next page is clicked

Comment: if it's doing an ajax call for the next page, there's still a URI (url) it is preforming call to in order to get the next page.

The most basic difference between a get and a post is the parameters in a post are part of the body of the request instead of being in the uri.  Look through the jersey client documentation and see how to construct a post request.